# How to Split a String at commas(,) but ignore commas inside double quotes(",")

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, case-class

I have a textfile string with format below:

```
"1","1st",1,"Allen, Miss Elisabeth Walton",29.0000,"Southampton","St Louis, MO","B-5","24160 L221","2","female"
```

I want to split the string at commas(,) but ignore the commas(,) inside the double quotes(""). I am using Spark and Scala and case class to create dataframe.
I tried the code below but I got an error:

```
val tit_rdd = td.map(td=>td.split(",(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")).map(td=>tit(td(0).replaceAll("\"","").toInt ,
                                                            td(1).replaceAll("\"",""),
                                                            td(2).toInt,
                                                            td(3).replaceAll("\"",""),
                                                            td(4).toDouble,
                                                            td(5).replaceAll("\"",""),
                                                            td(6).replaceAll("\"",""),
                                                            td(7).replaceAll("\"",""),
                                                            td(8).replaceAll("\"",""),
                                                            td(9).replaceAll("\"","").toInt,
                                                            td(10).replaceAll("\"","")))
```

The Case Class code is given below:

```
case class tit (Num: Int, Class: String, Survival_Code: Int, Name: String, Age: Double, Province: String, Address: String, Coach_No: String, Coach_ID: String, Floor_No:Int, Gender:String)
```

Error:

```
17/05/21 14:52:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:40)
    at $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NumberFormatException` is due to the empty number in your data and you are trying to convert it into `Integer` by using `.toInt`

The solution to this would be to use `Try` and `getOrElse` as below

```
val tit_rdd = td.map(td=>td.split(",(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)"))
  .map(td=>tit(Try(td(0).replaceAll("\"","").toInt) getOrElse 0 ,
  td(1).replaceAll("\"",""),
  Try(td(2).toInt) getOrElse 0,
  td(3).replaceAll("\"",""),
  Try(td(4).toDouble) getOrElse 0.0,
  td(5).replaceAll("\"",""),
  td(6).replaceAll("\"",""),
  td(7).replaceAll("\"",""),
  td(8).replaceAll("\"",""),
  Try(td(9).replaceAll("\"","").toInt) getOrElse 0,
  td(10).replaceAll("\"","")))
```

**That should solve the issue**

Another way of converting your text file to `dataFrame` would be to use `databricks csv reader`

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("path to the text file")
```

This will generate default `header names` like `_c0`, `_c1`
What you can do is put the `header line` in your text file and define `option` in the above line as

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", true).load("path to the text file")
```

You can play with more options yourself

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you, first replace all ","(splitable) to "#", then spilt by "#".

```
scala> st.replace("""","""", "#").replace("""",""","#").replace(""","""", "#").replace(""""""", "").split("#").map("\"" + _ + "\"")
res1: Array[String] = Array("1", "1st", "1", "Allen, Miss Elisabeth Walton", "29.0000", "Southampton", "St Louis, MO", "B-5", "24160 L221", "2", "female")
scala> res1.size
res2: Int = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spark's built-in [csv reader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark-CSV to load the `csv` data where it handles all comma inside double quotes.

Here is how you can use it

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

  val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val titschema = Encoders.product[tit].schema

  val dfList = spark.read.schema(schema = titschema).csv("data.csv").as[tit]

  dfList.show()

  case class tit(Num: Int,
                 Class: String,
                 Survival_Code: Int,
                 Name: String,
                 Age: Double,
                 Province: String,
                 Address: String,
                 Coach_No: String,
                 Coach_ID: String,
                 Floor_No: Int,
                 Gender: String)
```

I hope this helps!

If you want to create a schema same as the  SQLContext.createDataFrame does
you can use Scala Reflection as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
val titschema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[tit].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```